# How to let enumeration start at (0) automatically?

Tags: lists, numbering, enumerate

As we know the enumeration usually begin at (1), then followed by (2), (3),...

My question: How to start at (0)? I know \item[(0)] will work, but how do I do this automatically? That is, make it as a default option.

Comment: With the `enumitem` package just say `\setlist[enumerate,1]{start=0}`

Comment: @egreg Yes, it works, thank you. However, the second layer will start at () instead of (a)...

Comment: There is no zero'th letter, so `\arabic*` is the only format supporting zero

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I really don't know why one should want it. However, here's a solution with the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{start=0} % only outer nesting level
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item zero
\item one
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item b
  \end{enumerate}
\item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "I thought that by now professional programmers knew how much more preferable it is to let the natural numbers start at 0." -[Dijkstra, _On a Somewhat Disappointing Correspondence_](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD10xx/EWD1009.html)

Comment: @ben Yes, the natural numbers start at zero, but you're numbering the *first* item. Before any item the number of items is zero, when the first item appears it has number one.

Comment: One reason you might want to do this is if you are numbering a list of items that correspond to 'real' things numbered from zero. For example, I teach a course that starts in "0th week" (the week before the calendar start of term). It would be confusing if the 0th week topic was numbered 1. in the list.

Comment: @Ubiquitous I'm not saying it's always wrong to start at 0. But Dijkstra's idea was misunderstood by the OP

Comment: Another example is when describing algorithms. The initialization step is often referred to as the 0th step.

Answer (score 12):

You can also achieve it locally within the environment by using:

```
\setcounter{enumi}{-1}
```

---

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bf 1:,labelindent=10pt,leftmargin=*]
    \setcounter{enumi}{-1} 
\item zero
\item one
    \begin{enumerate}[\bf i:,labelindent=10pt,leftmargin=*] 
        \setcounter{enumii}{-1} 
        \item Nothing %testing with \roman, equivalent bold using \bf i
        \item one
        \item two
    \end{enumerate}
\item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Status:

SUCCESS

[image]

Comment: It seems better to use `start = 0` as an optional argument to each local environment.

Comment: Note that none of the package inclusions are needed to make this method work.  This is a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

This simple trick does the job:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[0.] Zero
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: NB The OP is aware of this solution ("I know \item[(0)] will work") and is looking for an automatic implementation of the zero-based counting.