# How to get different types of enumerates in one document

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I want to include different enumerations in my paper. For Section 1, I want to have the enumerate the this:

[image]

However, for the code below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\settozero{\setcounter{enumii}{-1}\renewcommand\theenumii{\arabic{enumii}}}
\newenvironment{myenumerate}  {\begin{enumerate}\ifx\c@enumii\undefined\relax\else\settozero\fi}    {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{enumerate}
\item  
\begin{myenumerate}
\item  I do not feel sad. 
\item  I feel sad 
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it. 
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{myenumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item  blah blah :\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item blah blah
\item blah blah\end{enumerate}
\item blah blah
\end{enumerate}
```

\end{document}

I get

[image]

How could I fix this?

Comment: You can see this post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100866/154390), to start from 0, also you can redefine some counters: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple with `enumitem`: you have the `start=` key to control the initial value of the counter. Further, the sub-enumerates in both sections are aligned:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(1), start = 0]
\item I do not feel sad.
\item I feel sad
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it.
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item blah blah :
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item blah blah
    \item blah blah
    \end{enumerate}
\item blah blah
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the good old enumerate package this is rather easy (unless I am missing something).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item  
\begin{enumerate}[(1)] \setcounter{enumii}{-1}
\item  I do not feel sad. 
\item  I feel sad 
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it. 
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item  blah blah :\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item blah blah
\item blah blah\end{enumerate}
\item blah blah
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]